# How to make a form from a specific table and save it to a different table

Tags: python, django, forms

According to my very little knowledge, whenever we make a form, it extracts the form from  a table and saves it to the same table.
for example:

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
     class Meta:
          model=Example
```

Here the `ExampleForm` is formed from `Example` model and once submitted it is saved back to `Example` model.
What i want is, I want to develop a form from a table and save it to another table?
Is this possible?

**Why do i want this?**

Because, i am creating a form, that contains only checkboxes and labels of these checkboxes are retrieved from a table, but i want to save the user input into a different table

**models.py**

```
class Offer(models.Model):

    package = models.ForeignKey(Package)
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    transportation = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    nextTrip = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True,blank=True)
    rewardPoints = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,null=True,blank=True)
    refferals = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=REFERRAL_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.package.packageTitle
```

`Offer` model is used to create the form, but once the data is submitted, it should be saved in `OfferRequest` model

```
class OfferRequest(models.Model):   
    offerReq = models.ForeignKey(Offer,null=True)
    userReq = models.ForeignKey(User)
    discountReq = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transportationReq = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    nextTripReq = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rewardPointsReq = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refferalsReq = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.discountReq
```

**forms.py**

```
class OfferRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    discountReq = forms.BooleanField(required=False,label="Discount")
    transportationReq = forms.BooleanField(required=False,label="Transportation")
    nextTripReq = forms.BooleanField(required=False,label="Next Trip")
    rewardPointsReq = forms.BooleanField(required=False,label="Reward Points")
    refferalsReq = forms.BooleanField(required=False,label="Refferals")
    class Meta:
        model = OfferRequest
        fields = ("discountReq","transportationReq","nextTripReq","rewardPointsReq","refferalsReq")
```

Since i am making the form from `OfferRequest`, it is rendered as shown below:

> () discount
>   () transportation
>   () nextTrip
>   () refferals
>   () rewardPoints

but what i want is :

> () discount : 3%
>   () transportation :FREE
>   () nextTrip :20%
>   () refferals : Yes
>   () rewardPoints : 200

The above form output can be rendered if the form is derived from `Offer` model, because the different offers are defined in the `Offer` model

Now when this form (derived from `Offer`) is submitted, i want it to get saved in `OfferRequest`

---

Trying my best to explain, do ask if something not clear.

Comment: Create another form from another table. While saving the data during handling of `POST`, use the 2nd form.

Comment: Can you make it a bit more clear. i dint understand the 2nd part on how to use the 2nd form while handling POST. Would be nice if you could give an example by giving a code snippet

Comment: Didn't get what you want.  I see that `OfferRequestForm` is created from `OfferRequest`, not the `Offer`. May be you mean that you want to set the `OfferRequest.offerReq` to some `Offer` model while saving the `OfferRequestForm`?

Comment: @catavaran: added more data to the question to give you a better picture

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `Offer`'s values to the field labels of the `OfferRequestForm` then you should override the `__init__()` method:

```
class OfferRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        offer = kwargs.pop('offer')
        super(OfferRequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in offer._meta.fields:
            field_name = field.name
            form_field_name = field_name + 'Req'
            if form_field_name in self.fields:
                self.fields[form_field_name].label += \
                                u': %s' % getattr(offer, field_name)
```

So now you have to pass the `offer` argument to the `OfferRequestForm`'s constructor:

```
def offer_req(request, offer_id):
    offer = get_object_or_404(Offer, pk=offer_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form  = OfferRequestForm(request.POST, offer=offer)
        if form.is_valid():
            offer_request = form.save(commit=False)
            offer_request.offerReq = offer
            offer_request.userReq = request.user
            offer_request.save()
            return redirect(offer_request)
    else:
        form  = OfferRequestForm(offer=offer)
    return render(request, 'offer_req.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: i am kind of new to django, so it would be nice if u could explain the first part or atleast point out some references needed to understand it

Comment: The good explanation of `model._meta`: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/04/working-models/  So we iterate over the model's fields and check if the `<fieldname>Req` field exists in the form (`self.fields` is a list of form fields). If such field exist then we change it's label.